# SQL correlated sub-queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following problem:

> Some countries have populations more than three times that of any of their neighbours (in the same continent). Give the countries and continents.

My query:

```
select name,continent from world x 
where population > 
(select 3*min(population) from world y 
where x.continent=y.continent 
group by y.continent)
```

The syntax is correct but the output is wrong. I know this can be done with joins, there are also different ways to do this which is already listed in Stack Overflow. But I want to know what is wrong with my logic.

This question is the last question given in http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Despite what you say this doesn't syntax (and group by y.continent) is invalid - did you post the correct code?

Comment: Sorry, that 'and' was pasted by mistake. I have edited the question.

Comment: I have given the link to the webpage containing the question and sample data set.

Comment: Is a 'neighbour' *any* country in the same continent? (I'd hardly think of Morocco and South Africa as neighbours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is correct.

GROUP BY is not a condition to compare, thus you have an invalid logical operation "AND" there. Delete "AND" & everything should work as you needed.

As P.Salmon also stated:

"GROUP BY" is a separate operation from "WHERE". However "GROUP BY" is logically connected to "min(population)" function. Instead of min returning the lowest pop on table, with "GROUP BY continent" it returns min population from each continent.

[Examples SQLFiddle for further fiddling](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b66c7/8)

Comment: Sorry,I have accidentally typed an extra 'and'. I have edited the question.

Comment: @jibinmathew Any neighbor means all neighbors

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on where caluse `and group by`

If I understand correct you can do this.

```
SELECT x.NAME, 
       x.continent 
FROM   world x 
INNER JOIN world  y
ON x.continent=y.continent
group by x.continent,x.name,x.population
Having x.population > min(y.population)*3
```

**EDIT**

I saw your edit questions .

You can use `ALL` to compare all country which in the same `continent`.

```
Select x.name,x.continent 
from world x  
Where x.population > ALL(
   Select y.population*3
   From world y
   Where x.continent=y.continent and x.name!=y.name
)
```

Comment: Neither the group by nor the subquery serve any useful purpose